# JSF required and hidden fields from db

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have jsf/primeface form components in my project. Also there are db table which describe which field should be required or hidden. This table is used by another system (which is not java related) so my project should also use that db table.

The problem is those fields and its ids are described as numbers in the db and in my project jsf/primefaces components have human readable ids. For example "name" field in db table has id = 1, required = 0, hidden = 1 and in xhtml I have:

`<p:inputtext id="idName" required="false" rendered="true"...>`

Is there any approach so that I can easily map `idName` component to database entry but not changing db table structure?

Comment: Maybe what you need is to use a `Converter`.

Answer (score 2):

Just create an entity representing the field:

```
public class Field {

    private Long id;
    private boolean required;
    private boolean hidden;

    // ...
}
```

and use it in your view as follows:

```
<p:inputText value="#{bean.values[field.id]}" required="#{field.required}" rendered="#{not field.hidden}" />
```

whereby `#{bean.values}` refers a `Map<Long, Object>`.

Comment: I have more than 200 such kind of fields and they all have different object values binded. e.g. one has `<p:inputText value="#{newComplaintMB.complaint.rmnr}"..>` another one has `<p:selectOneMenu value="#{newComplaintMB.accruement}"..>`. Should I add all in your suggested map initially?

Comment: You have field/property names in DB as well? I.e. it's possible to have a `public class Field { private String name; }`? If so, then use e.g. `#{newComplaintMB[field.name]}` whereby `#{field.name}` returns e.g. `accruement`.

Comment: With that approach can I use `#{newComplaintMB[field.name]}` whereby `#{field.name}` returns `complaint.rmnr` (property value from property values)?

Comment: In this scenario I should iterate over loop of components, but I also have tabs, wizards steps and different panels for different components